# @react-native-firebase_app' could not be found in project ':react-native-appgain-sdk-library

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

Where:
Build file '/node_modules/react-native-appgain-sdk-library/android/build.gradle' line: 80

What went wrong:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-appgain-sdk-library'.
Project with path ':@react-native-firebase_app' could not be found in project ':react-
```

native-appgain-sdk-library'.

Getting this error in running react-native run-android meanwhile ios app is running fine,

as i read it's dependency issue so i updated dependency inside node modules for both appgain-sdk and firebase

> node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/android/build.gradle

```
    import io.invertase.gradle.common.PackageJson

buildscript {
  // The Android Gradle plugin is only required when opening the android folder stand-alone.
  // This avoids unnecessary downloads and potential conflicts when the library is included as a
  // module dependency in an application project.
  if (project == rootProject) {
    repositories {
      jcenter()
      google()
      mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
      classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0")
      // originally it was this  classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3")
    }
  }
}

plugins {
  id "io.invertase.gradle.build" version "1.5"
}

def packageJson = PackageJson.getForProject(project)
def firebaseBomVersion = packageJson['sdkVersions']['android']['firebase']
def playServicesAuthVersion = packageJson['sdkVersions']['android']['playServicesAuth']
def jsonMinSdk = packageJson['sdkVersions']['android']['minSdk']
def jsonTargetSdk = packageJson['sdkVersions']['android']['targetSdk']
def jsonCompileSdk = packageJson['sdkVersions']['android']['compileSdk']
def jsonBuildTools = packageJson['sdkVersions']['android']['buildTools']

project.ext {
  set('react-native', [
    versions: [
      android : [
        minSdk    : jsonMinSdk,
        targetSdk : jsonTargetSdk,
        compileSdk: jsonCompileSdk,
        // optional as gradle.buildTools comes with one by default
        // overriding here though to match the version RN uses
        buildTools: jsonBuildTools
      ],

      firebase: [
        bom: firebaseBomVersion,
      ],

      play     : [
        "play-services-auth": playServicesAuthVersion,
      ],
    ],
  ])
}

apply from: file('./firebase-json.gradle')

// If data collection isn't specifically disabled, default is enabled
String dataCollectionDefaultEnabled = 'true'

if (rootProject.ext && rootProject.ext.firebaseJson) {
  if (rootProject.ext.firebaseJson.isFlagEnabled('app_data_collection_default_enabled', true) == false) {
    dataCollectionDefaultEnabled = 'false'
  }
}

android {
  defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
    manifestPlaceholders = [
      firebaseJsonDataCollectionDefaultEnabled: dataCollectionDefaultEnabled
    ]
  }
  lintOptions {
    disable 'GradleCompatible'
    abortOnError false
  }
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }

  sourceSets {
    main {
      java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/reactnative/java']
    }
  }
}

repositories {
  google()
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:${ReactNative.ext.getVersion("firebase", "bom")}")
  implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-common"
  implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:${ReactNative.ext.getVersion("play", "play-services-auth")}"
}

ReactNative.shared.applyPackageVersion()
ReactNative.shared.applyDefaultExcludes()
ReactNative.module.applyAndroidVersions()
ReactNative.module.applyReactNativeDependency("api")
```

> node_modules/react-native-appgain-sdk-library/android/build.gradle

```
// android/build.gradle

// based on:
//
// * https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.60-stable/template/android/build.gradle
//   original location:
//   - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.58-stable/local-cli/templates/HelloWorld/android/build.gradle
//
// * https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.60-stable/template/android/app/build.gradle
//   original location:
//   - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.58-stable/local-cli/templates/HelloWorld/android/app/build.gradle

def DEFAULT_COMPILE_SDK_VERSION = 31
def DEFAULT_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION = '30.0.2'
def DEFAULT_MIN_SDK_VERSION = 21
def DEFAULT_TARGET_SDK_VERSION = 31

def safeExtGet(prop, fallback) {
    rootProject.ext.has(prop) ? rootProject.ext.get(prop) : fallback
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven'

buildscript {
    // The Android Gradle plugin is only required when opening the android folder stand-alone.
    // This avoids unnecessary downloads and potential conflicts when the library is included as a
    // module dependency in an application project.
    // ref: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:build_script_external_dependencies
    if (project == rootProject) {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            jcenter()
            google()
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven'

android {
    compileSdkVersion safeExtGet('compileSdkVersion', DEFAULT_COMPILE_SDK_VERSION)
    buildToolsVersion safeExtGet('buildToolsVersion', DEFAULT_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION)
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion safeExtGet('minSdkVersion', DEFAULT_MIN_SDK_VERSION)
        targetSdkVersion safeExtGet('targetSdkVersion', DEFAULT_TARGET_SDK_VERSION)
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

repositories {
    // ref: https://www.baeldung.com/maven-local-repository
    maven { url "http://sdk.appgain.io/repository/maven-releases/" }

    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
    }
    maven {
        // Android JSC is installed from npm
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist"
    }
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(path: ":@react-native-firebase_app")
    implementation project(path: ":@react-native-firebase_analytics")
    implementation project(path: ":@react-native-firebase_messaging")
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    implementation 'io.appgain.sdk:appgain-android:4.1.24'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.11.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:18.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-beta04'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
    annotationProcessor  'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.10.0'
    api 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.7.2'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.19'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'

}

def configureReactNativePom(def pom) {
    def packageJson = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(file('../package.json').text)

    pom.project {
        name packageJson.title
        artifactId packageJson.name
        version = packageJson.version
        group = "io.appgain.reactsdk"
        description packageJson.description
        url packageJson.repository.baseUrl

        licenses {
            license {
                name packageJson.license
                url packageJson.repository.baseUrl + '/blob/master/' + packageJson.licenseFilename
                distribution 'repo'
            }
        }

        developers {
            developer {
                id packageJson.author.username
                name packageJson.author.name
            }
        }
    }
}

afterEvaluate { project ->
    // some Gradle build hooks ref:
    // https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/gradle-beyond-the/9781449373801/ch03.html
    task androidJavadoc(type: Javadoc) {
        source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
        classpath += files(android.bootClasspath)
        classpath += files(project.getConfigurations().getByName('compile').asList())
        include '**/*.java'
    }

    task androidJavadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: androidJavadoc) {
        classifier = 'javadoc'
        from androidJavadoc.destinationDir
    }

    task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
        classifier = 'sources'
        from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
        include '**/*.java'
    }

    android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
        def name = variant.name.capitalize()
        def javaCompileTask = variant.javaCompileProvider.get()

        task "jar${name}"(type: Jar, dependsOn: javaCompileTask) {
            from javaCompileTask.destinationDir
        }
    }

    artifacts {
        archives androidSourcesJar
        archives androidJavadocJar
    }

    task installArchives(type: Upload) {
        configuration = configurations.archives
        repositories.mavenDeployer {
            // Deploy to react-native-event-bridge/maven, ready to publish to npm
            repository url: "file://${projectDir}/../android/maven"
            configureReactNativePom pom
        }
    }
}
```

Appgain-sdk is on latest version, which is using firebase/app

What am i doing wrong which is causing the issue in build of android

also i have installed andorid platform and sdk tools from 27 till 31,

> andorid/build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "http://sdk.appgain.io/repository/maven-releases/" }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

> android/app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation. If none specified and
 *   // "index.android.js" exists, it will be used. Otherwise "index.js" is
 *   // default. Can be overridden with ENTRY_FILE environment variable.
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // https://reactnative.dev/docs/performance#enable-the-ram-format
 *   bundleCommand: "ram-bundle",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

/**
 * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
 *
 * This should be set on project.ext.react and mirrored here.  If it is not set
 * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
 * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
 */
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.deathfolder"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 17
        versionName "17.0"
        missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'
        missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'mlkit'
         multiDexEnabled true 
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            // Example: versionCode 1 will generate 1001 for armeabi-v7a, 1002 for x86, etc.
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        defaultConfig.versionCode * 1000 + versionCodes.get(abi)
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.6.0'
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
    // compile "com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.3.0"   //GIf
    // compile "com.facebook.fresco:animated-base-support:1.3.0"    //GIf
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-base-support:2.6.0'
    implementation project(':react-native-file-viewer')
    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.0.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation project(':react-native-push-notification')

    implementation 'io.appgain.sdk:appgain-android:4.1.24'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.19'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.7.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
    annotationProcessor  'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.10.0'
    // implementation project(path: ":@react-native-firebase_dynamic-links")
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
      exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.implementation
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
googleServices.disableVersionCheck = true
```

> android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you have conflicting dependencies that request two different versions of another dependency. Check the package.json of firebase/app and firebase/auth, if they are different versions you will need to find the conflicting dependency and either remove it or update it.

This can also occur if you are using `@react-native-firebase@6.2.0` you will need to update that as well.

You can also try removing the node-modules folder and reinstalling the dependencies.